# Expo encountered a fatal error: Error: Requiring unknown module "./locale/en-us"

Tags: react-native, expo, momentjs

I had to eject my Expo project last week, and I though everything was working fine (dev version).

I'm now testing on an actual device with a build (apk) and it crashes at boot. I used adb logcat for my device to print out the error and got this :

```
Requiring unknown module "./locale/en-US".
ReactNativeJS: Error: Requiring unknown module "./locale/en-us".
WARNING: getPackageName called on ScopedContext
WebViewFactory: Loading com.google.android.webview version 86.0.4240.198 (code 424019833)
AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
AndroidRuntime: Process PID: 21039
AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Expo encountered a fatal error: Error: Requiring unknown module "./locale/en-us"., stack:
AndroidRuntime: v@2:1305
AndroidRuntime: d@2:875
AndroidRuntime: vt@1203:16827
AndroidRuntime: pt@1203:16651
AndroidRuntime: kt@1203:16926
AndroidRuntime: I@694:2048
AndroidRuntime: _r@103:40603
```

I looked on StackOverflow and Google and it seems to be linked to the way moment requires locales. I tried every solutions I could find without any luck.

Anyone has an idea ? Thank in advance!

Comment: are u solve it?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using moment then the reason for that is `moment.locale('en-US')` not recognized, you need to use `moment.locale('en')` instead.